# Update grails domain, controller and view classes

Tags: grails, code-generation

I am new to the Grails framework.

After taking it for a bit of a spin, I created my own domain class and used the generate-all functionality to generate the controllers and the views. After this, I modified (added some more required functionality and removed somethings that were not required) the generated controllers and views. The application runs without a trouble.

Next, I require to make certain changes to my domain class for which i have already created and customized controllers and views. After making the change to the domain class, is there any way (or what is the correct way) to re-generate the controllers and view classes with my previous updates intact.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: casperOne has gone crazy here! just arrives to close questions! You need to have the requisite skills to answer such questions, which Molske and Jarred have!

Comment: This is a "real" question... not sure what the mod is on about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

execute grails install-templates to install the templates and modify them (http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html)

The next time you generate your view and/or controller, these changed templates will be used.

Comment: If your changes are generic enough (for example changing the layout/styling of the list.gsp or redirecting to the list page after saving an object) or your domain objects are changing rapidly I would make your changes to the templates and then use scaffolding (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html).  This can greatly help your development speed and once you get your view/controller/domain changes nailed down a little bit then you can generate the views.